# Add new blank rows into dataset by group (in R)

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, row, interpolation

I use R. I have dataframe like this:

```
dat <- data.frame(
  group = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2),
  horizon  = c(1,3,5,6,7,10,1,3,5,9,10),
  value = c(1.0,0.9,0.8,0.6,0.3,0.0,0.5,0.6,0.8,0.9,0.8)
  other = c(a,a,a,a,a,a,b,b,b,b,b)
)
```

And i would like to add row for every horizon that is missing (2,4,8 and 9 for the first group and 2,4,6,7,8 for the second group). Values (value) for the missing horizons would be blank.

I would like to get something like this:

```
datx <- data.frame(
  group = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2),
  horizon  = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
  value = c(1.0,"na",0.9,"na",0.8,0.6,0.3,"na","na",0.0,0.5,"na",0.6,"na",0.8,"na","na","na",0.9,0.8)
  other = c(a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b)
)
```

i.e. englarged dataset with new horizons, blank or "na" spaces in "value" variable and retained "other" variable.

This is just an example. I am actually working with a much larger dataset.

Without the groups, the problem would be much easier to solve, i would use something like this:

```
newdat <- merge(data.frame(horizon=seq(1,10,1)),dat,all=TRUE)
newdat <- newdat[order(newdat$horizon),]
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that the values in the variable `other` are the characters, `a` or `b`, and that this is completely redundant with your variable `group`. If this is the case, you could accomplish this with `full_join` in the `dplyr`package.

```
a="a"
b="b"
dat <- data.frame(
  group = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2),
  horizon  = c(1,3,5,6,7,10,1,3,5,9,10),
  value = c(1.0,0.9,0.8,0.6,0.3,0.0,0.5,0.6,0.8,0.9,0.8),
  other = c(a,a,a,a,a,a,b,b,b,b,b)
)

groups <- expand.grid(group=c(1,2),horizon=1:10)
groups <- groups %>% dplyr::mutate(other=ifelse(group==1,"a","b"))

dat %>%
  dplyr::full_join(groups,by=c('group','horizon','other')) %>%
  dplyr::arrange(group,horizon)
```

Comment: Thanks for help! The problem is that I have 80 other variables, not just that one (that was just an example). These variables never change within a "group" but it can happen that these variables sometimes have the same value for multiple "groups". 

So I'm trying to get these variables to extend to all horizons when the dataset is expanded by additional horizons. Only the "value" variable would have blank spaces left.

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)
fill = c("other")
RES = 
  dat[CJ(group = group, horizon = min(horizon):max(horizon), unique = TRUE), 
      on = .(group, horizon)
      ][, (fill) := lapply(.SD, \(x) x[which.min(is.na(x))]), by = group, .SDcols = fill]
   
RES[]
#     group horizon value  other
#     <num>   <int> <num> <char>
#  1:     1       1   1.0      a
#  2:     1       2    NA      a
#  3:     1       3   0.9      a
#  4:     1       4    NA      a
#  5:     1       5   0.8      a
#  6:     1       6   0.6      a
#  7:     1       7   0.3      a
#  8:     1       8    NA      a
#  9:     1       9    NA      a
# 10:     1      10   0.0      a
# 11:     2       1   0.5      b
# 12:     2       2    NA      b
# 13:     2       3   0.6      b
# 14:     2       4    NA      b
# 15:     2       5   0.8      b
# 16:     2       6    NA      b
# 17:     2       7    NA      b
# 18:     2       8    NA      b
# 19:     2       9   0.9      b
# 20:     2      10   0.8      b
#     group horizon value  other
```